# Start a background task from a Web Api request

Tags: task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api, tpl-dataflow

I have an ASP.WEB Web Api controller that needs to fire and forget some slow code. What would be a good way to do that? That is I want the controller to return an HTML response to the browser, while the slow code keeps running somewhere.

Is it a good idea to grab a worker thread from the tread pool and pass in a complex object created by the controller? Or do I need to write a separate windows service to do the work?

Comment: Do you need to send a response after the job completes?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution depends on the specifics or your situation and your workload.
You can certainly start of a new task [Factory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) when you receive a request.
There is nothing wrong with this technically.
Things you should think about though:

1. Do I have to return data back to the customer?
2. This task will use up web server resources so if those tasks take very long time and you get a lot of traffic you may run into situation where your customers are waiting in line to just start being processed. In this situation I think backend server with Windows Service be a much better idea.
3. All tasks above are subject to IIS Resets. They may be killed during processing your background task.